# How to get the last child of an HTMLElement

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a macro in Excel that opens and parses a website and pulls the data from it. The trouble I'm having is once I'm done with all of the data on the current page I want to go to the next page. To do this I want to get the last child of the "result-stats" node. I found the lastChild function, and so came up with the following code:

```
'Checks to see if there is a next page
If html.getElementById("result-stats").LastChild.innerText = "Next" Then
    html.getElementById("result-stats").LastChild.Click
End If
```

And here is the HTML that it is accessing:

```
<p id="result-stats">
    949 results
    <span class="optional"> (1.06 seconds)</span>
    <a href="/?query=omni%3DOklahoma%2BEnergy%2BAcquisitions" title="Modify your search">Modify search</a>
    <a href="#" id="toggle-show">Show more columns</a>
    <a href="/results/omni=Oklahoma+Energy+Acquisitions/page-2">Next</a>
</p>
```

When I try to run this, I get an error. After a lot of searching I think I found the reason. According to what I read, getElementById returns an element and not a node. lastChild only works on nodes, which is why the function doesn't work here.

My question is this. Is there a clean and simple way to grab the last child of an *element*? Or is there a way to typecast an element to that of a node? I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I've been at this way longer than I should have been. Any help anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: is the data in a table? if so check for the last row, or loop through the rows, and then when done click the link?\

Comment: The data comes from a website in which I am parsing through the HTML source code.

Comment: right, and does the source hold the items in tables ... so ... do you see `<t>` or `<td>` or `<tr>` tags?

Comment: Try `html.getElementById("result-stats").lastElementChild.Click`  You may be picking up a whitespace/text node using `LastChild`   http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_lastchild.asp

Comment: Not for this section of the html code no. Here's the website if that's more helpful: https://okcountyrecords.com/results/omni=Oklahoma+Energy+Acquisitions/page-1

Comment: html.getElementById("result-stats").lastElementChild still throws an error.

Comment: @Mike - There actually is a table. It's called `results-table`. You can get the max row of the table (`element.rows.count where element is the variable assigned to the table`), and loop through each row until you get to the max, then click on the `li` called `Next` ... you can find this by looping through `getElementsByTag("a") and check against the `innertext` property, I think .. sorry, I can't be more specific, i can't test IE VBA where I am currently am.

Comment: From what I see on the page source, the "results-table" table begins just after the thing I'm interested in (the link to the next page) and ends just before the duplicate link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I would take the link that you have https://okcountyrecords.com/results/omni=Oklahoma+Energy+Acquisitions/page-1 and change the 1 (of page-1) to 2, then 3, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a shell of how to do it. If my comments are not clear, ask away. I assumed knowledge of how to navigate to the page, wait for the browser, etc.

```
Sub ClickLink()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'load up page and all that stuff

'process data ...

'click link
Dim doc As Object
Set doc = IE.document

Dim aLinks As Object, sLink As Object

For Each sLink In doc.getElementsByTagName("a")

    If sLink.innerText = "Next" Then 'may need to play with this, if `innerttext' doesn't work
        sLink.Click
        Exit For
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great. I made one small change though and made sLink an IHTMLElement rather than an Object. The coder in me hates having generalized objects. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @mike - i agree with the generalized objects, but i was too lazy to look up the correct object type!